# ZonedDateTime returns wrong amount of months for a date until another end date

Tags: java, android, time, java-time

Using `ZonedDateTime.until` returns a wrong amount of months for a given date until a given end date. Looks like something to do with February ;)

This is the test I have written

```
    @Test
    fun `three months from end of november till first of march`() {
        val dateOfNow = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 30)
        val timeOfNow = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 1)
        val dateTimeOfNow = LocalDateTime.of(dateOfNow, timeOfNow)
        val timeZoneOfTestland = ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")
        val zonedDateTimeOfNow = dateTimeOfNow.atZone(timeZoneOfTestland)

        val dateEnd = LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 1)
        val timeEnd = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0)
        val dateTimeEnd = LocalDateTime.of(dateEnd, timeEnd)
        val zonedDateEnd = dateTimeEnd.atZone(timeZoneOfTestland)

        val until = zonedDateTimeOfNow.until(zonedDateEnd, ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
        assertEquals(3, until)
    }
```

And it returns 2 instead of expected 3.

The test succeeds when I change nano seconds of dateTimeOfNow

```
    val timeOfNow = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

But it fails again when I set the date to Nov 29th

```
    val dateOfNow = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 29)
    val timeOfNow = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 1)
```

In my point of view, it's clearly 3 months until March 1st 2023. In any case.

I tried it without year change using these dates

```
    val dateOfNow = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 31)
    val timeOfNow = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 1)
    val dateTimeOfNow = LocalDateTime.of(dateOfNow, timeOfNow)
    val timeZoneOfTestland = ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")
    val zonedDateTimeOfNow = dateTimeOfNow.atZone(timeZoneOfTestland)

    val dateEnd = LocalDate.of(2022, 5, 1)
    val timeEnd = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0)
    val dateTimeEnd = LocalDateTime.of(dateEnd, timeEnd)
    val zonedDateEnd = dateTimeEnd.atZone(timeZoneOfTestland)

    val until = zonedDateTimeOfNow.until(zonedDateEnd, ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
    assertEquals(3, until)
```

But it fails as well with `until == 2` instead of `3`.

Any explanation for that?

Comment: Counting months is not a well-defined business because months have uneven lengths. Each date library has its own way of doing it. I share your surprise in this case. It’s probably by design.

Comment: I looked into the implementation. What happens is that when the time-of-day of the end date-time is earlier than the time-of-day of the start date-time, the ***one day is subtracted from the end date***, yielding February 28, and then the difference is calculated based on the dates alone. From Nov 30 to Feb 28 is less then 3 months. It is probably in most cases a reasonable way to do it. Hardly here. I am even more surprised than I was when I posted my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following documentation from [`OffsetDateTime#until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) (emphasis mine):

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of
> **complete units** between the two date-times. For example, the amount in
> months between 2012-06-15T00:00Z and 2012-08-14T23:59Z will only be
> one month as it is one minute short of two months.

In your case, the difference is caused due to 1 nanosecond. Keep in mind that 2023-02-29 and 2023-02-30 do not exist.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 2 months
        // 2022-11-30T0:0:0:1 to 2022-12-30T0:0:0:1 - complete
        // 2022-12-30T0:0:0:1 to 2023-01-30T0:0:0:1 - complete
        // 2023-01-30T0:0:0:1 to 2023-03-01T0:0:0:1 would have been one month but
        // the endtime is 2023-03-01T0:0:0:0, 1 nanosecond short
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0, 1).until(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                ChronoUnit.MONTHS));

        // 3 months as explained above
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0, 1).until(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                ChronoUnit.MONTHS));

        // 3 months
        // 2022-11-30T0:0:0:0 to 2022-12-30T0:0:0:0 - complete
        // 2022-12-30T0:0:0:0 to 2023-01-30T0:0:0:0 - complete
        // 2023-01-30T0:0:0:0 to 2023-03-01T0:0:0:0 - complete
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).until(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                ChronoUnit.MONTHS));

        // 3 months
        // 2022-11-28T0:0:0:1 to 2022-12-28T0:0:0:1 - complete
        // 2022-12-28T0:0:0:1 to 2023-01-28T0:0:0:1 - complete
        // 2023-01-28T0:0:0:1 to 2023-02-28T0:0:0:1 - complete
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 11, 28, 0, 0, 0, 1).until(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2
3
3
3
```

Comment: Why is it two? Inn the example it completely makes sense. But in my case it's the full Dec, the full Jan and the full Feb until March 1st.

Comment: @axstel - I have added a couple of examples. I hope it makes it clear to you.

Comment: Interestingly, if I add a full other day, it fails.

`val dateOfNow = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 29)`

Comment: @axstel - 2023-02-29 or 2023-02-30 do not exist. I have added further comments in the code to make it clearer to you. Feel free to let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I think I got what you mean. But how would you calculate the time then correctly. For me it seems that there is an issue with February!?

I just have two dates. e.g. 2022-11-30 and  2023-03-01 and want to calculate the months between. Which are obviously 3 months. How would you do this? `.until()` seems to be not a good option

Comment: Looks like using Date instead of DateTime is the best way to calculate amount of months between two dates. Since my function gets has two ZonedDateTime parameters I'm going to do something like this

```
LocalDate.from(iteratedStart).until(LocalDate.from(endZonedDateTime), ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using Date instead of DateTime is the best way to calculate amount of months between two dates. Since my function gets has two ZonedDateTime parameters I'm going to do something like this

```
LocalDate.from(zonedDateTimeOfNow).until(LocalDate.from(zonedDateTimeEnd), ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
```